# Python redirect to page requested before authorization

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a portal(python3+flask) with authorization.
How can I make sure that when a user tries to access any page of the portal after authorization, the user is redirected not to a static page, but to the page that the user requested before the authorization page?

Comment: Are you using any libraries like [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? Can we see some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any code, its hard to help you - I'm going to assume that you aren't using a library like [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

That being said, take a look at [`request.referrer`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Request.referrer); once a user has successfully authenticated, you can just redirect the user to the URL value inside the referrer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The authorization code is unlikely to help, since after authorization it contains the usual `redirect(url_for('index')).`
Instead, I would like to return the user to where he originally wanted to go, before he was intercepted by the login page. Thank you very much for your help, `request.referrer` helped)